# SUMIFS for multiple criteria of numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this formula `=SUM(SUMIFS(EffortPC,TaskCode,RIGHT(C182,2)&"*",PostingDate,"<="&$A$1,PostingDate,">="&$A$1-DAY($A$1)+1-WEEKDAY($A$1-DAY($A$1)+2)+1,FeesOrExp,{"Disbursements","Subconsultants"}))` that works wonderful to sum for both **Disbursements** and **Subconsultants**.

I want to do something similar but instead have it sum for a variety of numbers. `=SUM(SUMIFS(EffortPC,TaskCode,{50&"*",51&"*"},PostingDate,"<="&DATE(YEAR($A$1),MONTH($A$1),DAY($A$1)),PostingDate,">="&$A$1-DAY($A$1)+1-WEEKDAY($A$1-DAY($A$1)+2)+1,FeesOrExp,"Professional Fees"))`. You can see I have it for 50&anything and 51&anything. However, I get the error message "There's a problem with this formula". I think it has to do with 50 being a number and not text. I tried putting an apostrophe in front of the 50 `'50&"*"` but that didn't work either. I still get the same error.

How can I add all of the 50 and 51's in `TaskCode`?

Comment: Are all the number a set number of digits: `51##` or `51###`?

Comment: try: `TaskCode,{50,51}&"*"`

Comment: @ScottCraner No they are not. Some are 50.A, some are 51.B, some are 52.A.1

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner

Comment: another option: `{"50*","51*"}`